# Is there a nice html5 2D graphics library that can be used nicely with Three.js?

Tags: html, graphics, canvas, 2d, three.js

I'm using Three.js to create some 3D graphics using webgl in a canvas element. Is there a nice library to draw 2D elements over the top of the 3D graphics. Something like the HUD of a 3D game. I want to draw some images or text on the screen over the 3D stuff. Any ideas? Can it be done with Three.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll notice in his examples that when he overlays 2D objects he just uses other HTML elements: http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_grid.html

It may be worth doing the same for yourself, where an entirely separate 2D canvas on top of the 3D one controls the HUD. There are some mouse-event related problems with that approach though, so it depends more precisely on what you need.

Comment: I believe that would be the way to go. He could use a library such as jQuery UI for the interaction features (draggable, droppable, resizable, selectable and sortable) and everything else that comes with it. In fact, I would not create another canvas but rather a layer over the canvas.

Comment: I agree with *Alerty*, but I would not create ui based on jquery since JavaScript is slow enough for webgl; considering the fact that webgl only supported by modern browsers (which they also support CSS3), I would go for lightweight ui based on new html5 technologies and very thin layer of JavaScript.